# Creating dynamic maps on the web

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, graphics, mapping, platform-agnostic

My company uses a sales model of dealers, territory managers and regional managers, each with a different level of area scope (IE manage based on zips codes, states, or regions.)

I want to create a slimmed down map that is similar to [this US state map](http://www.onlineatlas.us/map/united-states-map.gif) that would allow our users to manipulate who manages what.

What are some good resources to start down this path?

Comment: Your map link is broken.

Comment: Thanks, found another map.  Who would have thought the US government would break a link so quickly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[KML](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/mapsSupport.html) and [Tiger](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/)(US) or [Maps and Geo](http://www.statcan.gc.ca/mgeo/geography-geographie-eng.htm)(Can)? Or with something less interactive you could possibly still use the Topologically Integrated Geographic Encoding and Referencing system.

Comment: Is there also a Canadian equivalent to Tiger?

Comment: i didn't check too hard, but that looks like a decent entry point.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you could base yourself on [OpenStreetMap](http://openstreetmap.org/) which database is under creative commons license.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/) for storing the data, [MapServer](http://mapserver.osgeo.org/) for generating map tiles, and [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) for the interface should give you something to start with. Include a some PHP libraries, and your are just about there!

Answer (score 0):

One useful tool that I've found is the following [GPS Visualization](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/map_input?form=data).